# MPI_Allreduce failed in MPICH2

Tags: fortran, mingw, mpi, mpich

I recently working with MPI. I am still very new to MPI. But I recently find a problem when I using MPICH2. Here is my little fortran 90 program modified from Hello world program. I haven't test the c version of it but I think they should be very similar (differed by the function name and the error prameter).

I am working on Windows 7 64bit, MinGW (gcc version 4.6.2, and it is 32bit compiler) and using MPICH2 1.4.1-p1 32bit version. Here is the command that I used to compile the simple code:

```
gfortran hello1.f90 -g -o hello.exe -IC:\MPICH2_x86\include -LC:\MPICH2_x86\lib -lfmpich2g
```

And here is the simple code:

```
  program main
  include 'mpif.h'
  character * (MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME) processor_name
  integer myid, numprocs, namelen, rc,ierr
  integer, allocatable :: mat1(:, :, :)

  call MPI_INIT( ierr )
  call MPI_COMM_RANK( MPI_COMM_WORLD, myid, ierr )
  call MPI_COMM_SIZE( MPI_COMM_WORLD, numprocs, ierr )
  call MPI_GET_PROCESSOR_NAME(processor_name, namelen, ierr)

  allocate(mat1(-36:36, -36:36, -36:36))
  mat1(:,:,:) = 0
  call MPI_Bcast( mat1(-36, -36, -36), 389017, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr )
  call MPI_Allreduce(MPI_IN_PLACE, mat1(-36, -36, -36), 389017, MPI_INTEGER, MPI_BOR, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
  print *,"MPI_Allreduce done!!!"
  print *,"Hello World! Process ", myid, " of ", numprocs, " on ", processor_name
  call MPI_FINALIZE(rc)
  end
```

It can be compiled, but however it failed when running (maybe invalid memory access?). There must be some problem with MPI_Allreduce since it works fine if I remove that line. And it also works if I make the matrix smaller. I tried it on a ubuntu machine with same version MPI as well. No problem in Linux.

When I use gdb (comes with MinGW) to check (gdb hello.exe then backtrace). I got something meaningless (or seems to be for myself):

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 16316.0x4fd0]
0x01c03100 in mpich2nemesis!PMPI_Wtime ()
   from C:\Windows\system32\mpich2nemesis.dll
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x01c03100 in mpich2nemesis!PMPI_Wtime ()
   from C:\Windows\system32\mpich2nemesis.dll
#1  0x0017be00 in ?? ()
#2  0x00000000 in ?? ()
```

Does this actually mean there are something wrong with the windows version MPI library?
What will be the solution to make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: that 389017 , the int count part of mpi_bcast doesn't look right to me

Comment: also to test if the mpi library is working , why not find a nice mpi hello world example and see if that compiles

Comment: @pyCthon You are probably right, I got more direct error message with openmpi: [20989] *** An error occurred in MPI_Bcast
[20989] *** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
[20989] *** MPI_ERR_TYPE: invalid datatype
[20989] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (goodbye)

Comment: THis actually worked fine for me now that I was given a chance to run the code, i tested with mpif90 gcc45 4.5.4_1 so it's definitely a windows related error

Comment: Thanks pyCthon. As I said， the code works on  a Linux machine, but fail if you use MinGW + MPICH2 1.4.1p1. I downloaded MPI from MPICH2 official site. I'll ask this question in their mail list to see if they have an answer.

Comment: I want to test MPI_Allreduce. Hello world code works on all platforms. So I add MPI_Allreduce into Hello world just want to test it.

Comment: @pyCthon -- the 389017 looks fine to me.  It is `(36+36+1)**3` which is the size of the array being passed.

Answer (score 4):

This might not fix your problem, but `MPI_INT` is not a fortran-mpi datatype.  `MPI_INTEGER` is the corresponding datatype.  Different implementations may provide `MPI_INT` on the fortran side, but I'm pretty sure that this is not defined by the standard.  Try compiling your code with `IMPLICIT NONE` and see if it complains (also test if `MPI_INTEGER .ne. MPI_INT`).  If it complains, what is happening is that `MPI_INT` is getting assigned some value by the compiler (or your version of MPI uses `MPI_INT` for some other datatype...).  This may conflict with one of the pre-defined values set by MPI.  Thus, it is treating your array of integers as some other type which could result in a buffer overflow which can manifest itself in all kinds of funny ways.

Comment: Thanks a lot mgilson. Though it doesn't fix the MPI_Allreduce problem it is a good point! MPI_INTEGER and MPI_INT are different. They have different values (1275069467 and 1275069445). But even when I add implicit none, there is no error message regarding it. You are right. I should use MPI_INTEGER instead of MPI_INT.